# singular values of block positive matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we have real matrices $P,Q$. I was wondering if 
the eigenvalues of $[PP'\quad  PQ';\\ QP' \quad  QQ']$ could be related to the eigen values of $PP'+QQ'$? where $P'$ refers to the standard transpose.

Are there specific conditions on $P,Q$ based on which I can prove the eigen values of the block matrix are related to $PP'+QQ'$? Maybe, can we say, the the trace norm of the block matrix is at most the trace norm of $PP'+QQ'$?

Comment: What do you have in mind?

Comment: For unitary matrices and density matrices, it seems like the eigen values of the block matrix and $PP'+QQ'$ are the same. I was wondering if something like that held in general?

Comment: It reduces to the question, whether $MM'$ and $M'M$ have the same (**nonzero**) eigenvalues. This is indeed true. Consider the singular value decomposition of $M$.

Comment: Im sorry, I didnt get that last comment of urs. Isnt it true that the eigen values are the same?

Comment: $M'M$ may be invertible and thus $0$ is **not** an eigenvalue. But $MM'$ always has rank deficit. That is $0$ is an eigenvalue. Here, $M$ is any matrix with more rows than columns.

Comment: Im sorry, if everything was square matrices, then couldnt MM' and M'M both have full rank? Im sorry, im missing the point here..

Comment: In your case, you have $M = \begin{bmatrix} P \\ Q \end{bmatrix}$. So $M$ is never square. If $M$ is square than $MM'$ and $M'M$ have the same set of eigenvalues.

Comment: Right. So in one comment you mentioned it reduces to whether $MM'$ and $M' M$ have the same non-zero eigen values. What reduces to this question? Have we just concluded now that $M'M$  has the same eigen values as $PP'+QQ'$ (which makes sense), however $MM'$ is what I am interested in relating to the eigen values of $M'M$, what can be said about that? Are they the same, maybe by looking at the SVD?

Comment: I will post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M = \begin{bmatrix} P \\ Q \end{bmatrix}$. Then, we have
$$ MM' = \begin{bmatrix} PP' & PQ' \\ QP' & QQ' \end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$ M'M = PP' + QQ'. $$
That is, you asked whether $MM'$ and $M'M$ have the same set of eigenvalues.

In general that is not true, as $0$ is always an eigenvalue of $MM'$, whereas $M'M$ might be positive definite. For example consider 
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}. $$

However, $MM'$ and $M'M$ do have the same **nonzero** eigenvalues. Let $M=VSU'$ be the singular value decomposition of $M$. That is, $U$ and $V$ are unitary and $S$ is of the same size as $M$ and diagonal with the singular values on the diagonal. Then, we have
$$ MM' = VSS'V' $$
and
$$ M'M = US'SU'. $$
Now, $SS'$ and $S'S$ are square diagonal matrices and their nonzero diagonal elements are the same, namely the squared singular values of $M$.